# How do I correctly build my graph for the Hopcroft Karp Maximal Matching Algorithm in the current generic scenario given?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, matching

I'm solving an algorithmic problem which required me to learn a Maximal Matching algorithm. After spending a day learning and implementing it from various sources, I have understood the algorithm.

However, I'm unable to apply the algorithm (build the graph) for the current scenario.

Here it goes: I have 'n' boys and 'm' girls. Each of them has a 'Dancing Skill' and a boy can be paired with another girl iff either of their skill difference differs by 1 point. That is, absolute value (boy skill-girl skill)<=1.
**I have to find the maximum number of pairs that can be formed.**

I'm pretty sure my implementation of the Hopcroft Karp maximal matching algorithm is correct. The problem is the building of the graph. I have tried to build the graph in the following way in complexity O(n*m):

**For each boy indexed 1 to n, Search for the indices of the girls whose skill difference differs by 1 point. If found, add an undirected edge to the graph.** This seems entirely correct to me.

Could someone help me out?

Here is my code. As mentioned, the matching algorithm is right. The attention required is in the 'main' function where I build the graph:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;
#define pb push_back
#define sz 100001

int boysSkillz[sz], girlsSkillz[sz];

//Maximal Matching begins
vector<int> adj[sz];
int pairU [sz], pairV[sz], dist[sz];

bool HK_Bfs(int m)
{
    queue<int> Q;
    for (int u=1; u<=m; u++)
    {
        if (pairU[u]==0)
        {
            dist[u] = 0;
            Q.push(u);
        }
        else
            dist[u] = INT_MAX;
    }
    dist[0] = INT_MAX;
    while (!Q.empty())
    {
        int u = Q.front();
        Q.pop();
        if (dist[u] < dist[0])
            for (int v:adj[u])
                if (dist[pairV[v]] == INT_MAX)
                {
                    dist[pairV[v]] = dist[u]+1;
                    Q.push(pairV[v]);
                }
    }
    return (dist[0] != INT_MAX);
}

bool HK_Dfs(int u)
{
    if (u != 0)
    {
        for (int v: adj[u])
            if (dist[pairV[v]] == dist[u]+1 && HK_Dfs(pairV[v]))
            {
                pairV[v] = u;
                pairU[u] = v;
                return true;
            }
        dist[u] = INT_MAX;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int HopcroftKarp(int m, int n)
{
    for (int u=0; u<m; u++)
        pairU[u] = 0;
    for (int v=0; v<n; v++)
        pairV[v] = 0;
    int maxMatching = 0;

    while (HK_Bfs(m))
        for (int u=1; u<=m; u++)
            if (pairU[u]==0 && HK_Dfs(u))
                maxMatching++;
    return maxMatching;
}
//Maximal Matching ends

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cin>>boysSkillz[i];
    cin>>m;
    for(int i=1;i<=m;i++)
        cin>>girlsSkillz[i];
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) //Building graph according to logic mentioned
        for(int j=1;j<=m;j++)
            if(abs(boysSkillz[i]-girlsSkillz[j])<=1)
            {
                adj[i].pb(j);
                adj[j].pb(i);
            }
    cout<<HopcroftKarp(n,m);
    return 0;
}
```

The input is as follows. 'n' is the number of boys. Then 'n' integers for their skills. 'm' is the number of girls. Then 'm' integers for their skill.

Eg:

4
1 4 6 2
5
5 1 5 7 9

**The correct output for the input mentioned is 3**.
My code returns 4 which is wrong.

Everything in action: http://ideone.com/WOcE8I

Here's the link to the actual problem: http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/489/B

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: What should the output be? The given answer is 3, your code reports 4; which do you think is correct?

Comment: The correct answer is 3. My answer is 4 which is wrong. Is it not clear in the description?

Comment: No, your description doesn't mention the output. But it appears that girl #2 accepts the invitation of boy #4 after she's agreed to dance with boy #1; in your code, boys approach girls who are already taken.

Comment: In case the graph building in your opinion is wrong (which it ofcourse is), i'd like to know how to correct it. That is my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the second line of building the graph. **We cannot have same indices of boys and girls being paired with each other**. So the correct format would be:

```
adj[i].pb(j);
adj[j+n].pb(i); //This ensures indices assigned are distinct
```

This resolves the problem and should always be remembered while building a bipartite graph for max-matching